# Neo4j slow on windows 2016 datacenter

Tags: neo4j

Query takes 13 seconds on a 60g ram, 10 core, ssd server, but the same query on a 2014 macbook pro 16gb ram, i7 takes 4seconds, both client and server running on the same machine (Server: server-client, laptop:server-client) I am not querying the databse remotely.

There are 61000 persons in a database, I just want to get their info, but not all the nodes have the same number of properties

The query is basic:

```
MATCH(n:Person) return *
```

I expected to get way better results on the server than on my laptop. I would've expected to get under 1s

Comment: If your client is running on your laptop, then it takes extra time to receive 61K results from a *remote* server.

Comment: @cybersam The client and server run on the same machine in both cases. I'm not querying the server from the laptop... i have neo4j desktop on the laptop with the same database

Comment: Hi Rares, welcome to SO! I hope you're finding it awesome here >^_^< So, jumping into things, the problem with this question is that there are any number of reasons why a process might not be performing the same on a particular operating system as opposed to another. Getting a definitive answer is very difficult for us to do here. There could be workers on one box that aren't present on another, the binary for Neo4J might not be exactly the same, etc. I'd recommend taking a look at these tips, rewriting, and then we'll be able to better help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @RebeccaNelson thanks for the warm welcome :) Indeed i believe the binaries are not the same since one machine is running windows and the other macOs. I will take a look at the help resource suggested and rewrite my question asap.